# Importing Props from Redux directly into function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have different kinds of interactive forms within my page. Each of them dispatch the same function that sends their data to me via E-Mail. But every time I send this data I would like to add the user profile and E-Mail from within my redux store. I don't want to be forced to pass this information via props, every time.

Is there a way to import props from the redux store directly into my external function, without having it pass it as a prop?

Comment: Can you show code related to your question?

Comment: This is more of a general question. Can I have a function that imports it's own Props from the redux store?

Comment: Im not sure if this will solve the problem you are having, but you could use connect from react-redux to connect the form component, and inject the values from state into the form component to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "right" answer is to use the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware.  Turn your function into a thunk action creator, connect the component, and dispatch the thunk function, then use `getState()` inside of the thunk to access the values from the store.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed